# "New users" reputation tab should be removed (or at least changed) from per site metas

Tags: feature-request, reputation, per-site-meta

Per site metas don't have visible reputation for users. But the user list on the [new users tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newusers) sorted by reputation contains users with no activity on meta.

> [image: new-user-rep]

The [top new user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7518718/bartek-fryzowicz) hasn't actually participated on meta:

> [image: no-meta]

I think the reputation tab should be removed from per site metas, or should reflects user's meta-reputation (like for badge earning), or should be replaced with [participation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=participation) tab restricted for new users only.

Comment: There is no meta reputation so your last point doesn't make sense. If you're going to get rid of the "reputation" tab then you should get rid of the whole "new users" tab, because the only other option is equally nothing to do with meta.

Comment: @Cai actually you can see [score of you answers/question by tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4xUW.png) in the tooltip text of the profile. Sorting on reputation tab for meta site could be based on such information.

Comment: Well that is your net score, which is not the same as reputation, but yeh replacing it with a "participation" tab makes sense I guess. Personally I think it would be better to *add* a meta-participation tab *as well* as the normal reputation tab; it can be useful to see how active on meta new users are